# Lyx - weird PDF outputs

Tags: lyx

I have a problem with my LyX PDF outputs.

When I export LyX file to PDF using `pdflatex` letters are thicker on a page where `.png` graph is inserted than on other pages. Same thing with 'LuaTeX' and 'XeTeX'.

Different problems occur when I use `dvipdfm` and `ps2pdf`. Then my graphs imported from `.pdf` files are blurred (low resolution) but there is no problem with thicker letters ...